# How can I create a scheduler/kanban view of appointments

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm creating an UWP/tablet application in Xamarin.forms where I want to achieve a scheduler/kanban view of my data, so that
- Persons are columns
- Time (hours) are rows
- Appointments are cards

Yes, just like an Outlook day view with multiple persons.

I have a basic layout working with a grid created in code-behind. When doing a refresh though, I'm doing a completely new grid and the UI flashes when I replace the old grid with the new.

I've tried Syncfusion and they unfortunately doesn't support this view as of now.

**My question is:**

> Am I doing this all wrong? Should I been looking in another direction
>   using what-ever method/framework/approach.

Input much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using a third party component [SfKanban](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/kanban-board/overview)

Comment: Yes. But their kanban doesn't support swimlanes. So even though it looks great, it's not that functional.